# How can you tell the gun type on top of the jeeps in Far Cry 2?

Tags: far-cry-2

I've been playing Far Cry 2 on Infamous (hardest) difficulty lately.  Without question the most common vehicle in Far Cry 2 is the Assault Truck.

[image: Assault Truck]

Mounted on top of it is a machine gun.  The machine gun, like all mounted video game guns, has infinite ammo, which is awesome, and I use it constantly in all my drive-by shootings.

About once in every ten times, though, I start pulling the trigger to induce some high-velocity lead poisoning and discover that instead of the pleasing yet somehow anemic "*dakka dakka dakka dakka*" noise I get a much more thrilling "bamp! bamp! bamp! bamp!" and my hapless victims seem to die much more quickly.

How can I guarantee I'll get a truck with this beefier gun all the time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is how it works:

If you perform all buddy missions in the north, the trucks that spawn outside your safehouses come with a M2 .50 Cal rather than a regular M-249 SAW. (The M2 is probably what you're noticing.)

If you perform all buddy missions in the south, they come with a MK-19 grenade launcher.

I'm not sure there's any way you can reliably find a car with an M2 "in the wild".

Comment: Haven't yet been able to confirm this is the case.  I just had a random encounter with two soldiers driving a truck with a grenade launcher on it.  I haven't done any of the buddy missions in the south yet.  Not sure what this means in terms of availability.

Comment: Completed all buddy missions in the north.  Trucks did not spawn with M2 in the south.  Will try to complete all buddy missions in the south and see what happens.

Comment: As it turns out the answer is that the vehicle weapons are a safe house upgrade.  You don't have to do the "Mike's Bar" buddy missions, just the secondary phone call missions you get after accepting a major mission for the UFLL or APR.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it has to do with your progress but you have to unlock the south area first i think then If it has a long barrel that is The M2.50 cal if the barrel is short that is the M-249 Saw (which can be purchased at gun shops. If the gun has a large magazine box (the green thing which houses the ammunition) that is the Mk-19 Grenade launcher. And you can not guarantee that it will be the one you choose to have.